# How to add a default value for an input field

Tags: html

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh7fC.png)

When I click into an input field, the default value shouldn't be selectable and when I start typing the default value should disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `placeholder`

```
<input placeholder="text">
```

Comment: And how to change color of that placeholder?

Comment: @QuanVu https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp

Comment: thanks, and wait, i must be wait 4 minutes to accept your answer.